# php validation for NTP server

Tags: php, javascript, ntp

I want to add NTP validation in php anyone can help me ?

some of the example of NTP server are :-

nist1-ny.ustiming.org
nist1-nj.ustiming.org
nist1-pa.ustiming.org
time-a.nist.gov
time-b.nist.gov

Comment: Yeah, this makes no sense really. The system time should be controlled by the OS usually. What are you trying to do?

Comment: actualy i make an software in which users add NTP ... like OS

Comment: for more details see http://tf.nist.gov/tf-cgi/servers.cgi

Comment: @Harry what do you mean by "add NTP"?

Comment: @Pekka: probably he means that he is writing a service that will be able to store some list of NTPs. Thus he need to check if the passed domain name serves valid NTP service.

Comment: I had a similar need, and posted my solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21805579/418584

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The NTP protocol seems to be pretty straight forward.

[Here](http://www.kloth.net/software/timesrv1.php) is a code snippet that claims to be able to fetch the date and time from a NTP server.

I have no experience with it, but it looks good.