# An Alternative To Time()

Tags: php, time

I have a PHP script that currently pulls the time from the server using time();

Unfortunately the time on the server has recently been wrong and ahead of time
before it updates/resets. The hosting support have looked into the issue but as yet
it hasn't been resolved and it's on-going.

For this script I need the time to be relatively accurate so thought I might be
able to put in a temporary fix until such time as the above problem is resolved.

I have tried to look at various other methods of getting the time like from NIST or 
there was some mention about getting it from the headers. I am worried though about
slowing the script down and am not sure what the best method would be.

BTW The PHP Version is 4.4 - yes I know it should be changed but that's not in
my control as it's on a shared server.

So any suggestions as to how to obtain the current time - not server time and 
to have it as a unix timestamp like time();

Thanks for any help.

Comment: `PHP 4.4` ??? No longer supported .. that more problem that your time issue

Comment: I'd seriously consider changing hosting. Most shared servers nowadays offer at least 5.x, and if yours is also having problem with linux time... :/

Comment: I know what you are saying folks but at the moment I can't do that unfortunately.

Comment: Hello, and so only adjusting the [timezone](http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php) setting can not help to correct that timestamp?

Comment: no the server time gains time - yesterday it was 30+mins ahead - today 40+mins ahead

Answer (score 3):

I know you know this, but 4.4 serious?? Don't you care about security at all?

To answer your question if you do not want to rely on the time-settings of the server what about calling some NTP server to request the current date/time?

http://www.pool.ntp.org/

After some searching I found this maybe duplicate: [php validation for NTP server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5777132/php-validation-for-ntp-server)

<sub>Also note that flaky times may be caused by other more severe problems ahead.</sub>

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Yes I care about security and on my own dedi and VPS they have the latest versions. This is a shared server not under my control and the site has built up over 12 years on the same server.

Answer (score 0):

Make a script that gets the time from any server. Like the NIST server you suggested. Or use timeanddate.com. You can use file_get_contents() (php4.3+) Try `file_get_contents("http://free.timeanddate.com/clock/i3l84w5k/tt0/tw0/tm3/td2/th1/ta1/tb3")` Use a regexp to extract the time string. And then turn that time string into a timestamp using `strtotime()`.

Have this script call time() and substract the time returned timestamp from to the time(stamp) of the remote host.

Now write this offset to a cache, database or file.

And put this script in a cron job.

And write a function myTime() that reads the offset from the cache/database/file and adds it to time().

---

**edit** : I worked it out a bit:

Run this script periodically with a cronjob:

```
date_default_timezone_set("UTC");
$html = file_get_contents("http://free.timeanddate.com/clock/i3l84w5k/tt0/tw0/tm3/td2/th1/ta1/tb3");
preg_match('/id=t1>(.*)</U',$html, $matches);
$timeStamp = strtotime($matches[1]);
$offset = time() - intval($timeStamp);
$fh = fopen("time_offset.txt", "w");
fwrite($fh, $offset);
fclose($fh);
```

Use this function to get the adjusted time:

```
function myTime() { return time() - intval(file_get_contents("time_offset.txt")); }
```